# Unathorized response or any other status code causes 500 error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am using .net core API for a simple api endpoint.

I do some checks to determine if a user is authnticated and then i use the Unathorized response which i use in my front end to display my message.

```
if(!IsAuthenticated)
{
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

Simple as that. Locally works fine.

When i upload in server this code throws an error 500. Server has the exact same version of .net core (2.2). Even if i return StatusCode.401 or any other status i still get error 500. I tried to catch the error, view the Event Viewer but i only get a generic 500 error.

Clearly there is something wrong with StatusCodes in server but i don't get it. Has anyone experienced similiar issue?

Comment: did you check your server API with postman or some other tool?

Comment: @as.if.i.code yes just a simple error 500 no information at all

Comment: Show some more details of your code.

Comment: its near impossible to see what is going on here, are you using developer and production message handling?

Comment: Maybe your code throw an exception when executed on the remote server. So the returned status is 500 rather than anything else you expect. Add logs to your application. As other said, it's hard to debug with only those information.

Comment: @GuillaumeSasdy The thing is that Unathorized() is to blame because when i return a custom Json object its fine. But yes i understand that you need more info  - even i do :P

Comment: Is there a proxy between your server and the client that might re-route all unauthorized error thrown by your app. as error 500? or even maybe IIS itself could be configured to re-route error.